# spark_apply does not distribute. There is only one R task in a node

Tags: r, apache-spark, apply, sparklyr

I have a Spark data frame **SDF.data** partitioned into **6 partitions**.

My **Sparklyr** *(0.6.4)* runs on **3 executors**.

I am trying to produce a data frame formed from the products of some columns in **SDF.data** according to the table **df.SplitNames**.
The **spark_apply** function looks like the following:

```
spark_apply(SDF.data,function(df){
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df.prod <- df[ , mget( as.character(df.SplitNames$X1[df.SplitNames$Interact]) )] *  
df[ ,mget(as.character( df.SplitNames$X2[df.SplitNames$Interact]) )]
setDF(df.prod)
return(df.prod) 
}) -> SDF.data.interact
```

However, the process never finishes. When I check the processes in each node with **top**, I see there is an R task running in 1 node. That's it!

I expected the function inside spark_apply to be distributed to all nodes. It does not seem to be the case.

I am doing something wrong, or is there a bug with **spark_apply**?

Comment: In the Spark webgui, the **Executors** tab shows also that there is only **1 Active Tasks**

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing here. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout your spark ui at executor page stdout. it seems your data is put on one machine instead of 3.

`SDF.data = sdf_repartition(SDF.data,partitions = 20,partition_by = "your_key")`

after repartition, you can call spark_apply faster.